# Excel Formula for Weekdays Only

Tags: excel

I am using this formula to calculate averages in a column. Can someone please help me to have this only calculate for "weekdays"?  Thanks for any help.                                                                      `=AVERAGEIF($D$2:$D$1317, ">=" & (TODAY()), $E$2:$E$1317)`

Comment: Use `averageifs(...`, instead of `averageif(...`.  That will allow you to put multiple criteria in.  Build your criteria with `weekday(...`

Comment: Excel 2010. Would I just put weekday first?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit lengthy but makes the average calculation a bit simpler.

List the dates in a column as shown:

```
Date        Day        Indicator
6/4/2015    Thursday      1
6/5/2015    Friday        1
6/6/2015    Saturday      0
6/7/2015    Sunday        0
6/8/2015    Monday        1
6/9/2015    Tuesday       1
6/10/2015   Wednesday     1
```

To get the day, use this formula `=TEXT(A2,"dddd")` This returns the day of the week in words.

Next create the indicator using this `=IF(B2="Saturday",0,IF(B2="Sunday",0,1))` this indicates if it's a weekday.

Then us `=AVERAGEIF($D$2:$D$1317, "!=0",$E$2:$E$1317)`

This should work. It's a bit of a work around. But I've always found using multiple steps rather than a complicated formula is better in Excel.